# Using Webpack to compile scss in a separate css file while keeping original urls for images

Tags: css, sass, webpack

I've learned how to include scss files inside a javascript using file Webpack but now I want to generate a css file from a scss. I'm using ExtractTextPlugin to do this and I could generate a css file but the problem is that inside my scss file, I'm setting some background images like:

```
   background: url("../img/test.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

Now, I realized that when extracting into a separate css file, the images are incorporated in that file, increasing the size from 6 kb to 400 kb for the different images so I can't load the styles quickly.

I want to ignore including the images inside the generated css file and just keep the url like they are so that they could be requested like they would normally do from a css file. I've read some articles related to that but I still can't figure it out.

The loaders I'm using are:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")
 },
 {
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass')
 },
 {
   test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
   loader: "url-loader"
 },
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are those images files in css are data objects? if yes then it is done by url-loader you can set limit for this using url-loader?limit=10000 as loader or just try using file-loader. You can increase the limit as per your requirements

Comment: Hi! Using:
{
   test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
   loader: "file-loader?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]"
 }
works, it doesn't include the files inside the generated css file, but then, the problem is in the urls, because in my SCSS I have url("../img/mentions/spotlight.jpg"); and also url("../img/woman.jpg"), so in the CSS file and with the name query in the file-loader ([path][name].[txt]), the urls are:

url(src/img/mentions/spotlight.jpg); and url(src/img/woman.jpg) respectively.

So this represents a problem because it's keeping the src/ path, when my styles.css is in the public.

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out how to solve the problem, we just need to use file-loader instead of url-loader and set the context like:

```
{
   test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
   loader: "file-loader?emitFile=false&name=[path][name].[ext]&context=src/"
}
```

With the context query, all the url paths keep like they should be.